# Center menu navigation

Tags: html, css, center, nav

I have figured out how to center the logo, but cannot get the navigation to center as well. Hopefully you guys can help!

Code for centering logo:

```
#header #logo{
float: none !important;
}

#header hgroup { 
float: none !important;
text-align: center !important;
}
```

I know this is pretty basic, but I would love some help. Thank you. See my website [here](http://www.lostgrok.com).

Comment: It should be as simple as setting the left and right margins to auto on the navigation element, or setting text-align to center and ensuring the child items weren't floated, but unfortunately your CSS seems to be a bit nightmarish to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
#navigation{
    float:none;
    text-align:center;
}

#navigation > ul{
    float:none !important;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `text-align: center` on the `<nav>` tag and `display: inline-block` to the `<ul>`.

You also need remove `float: right` from `#header #navigation` and `#header #navigation ul.nav`.

You also don't need `#header #navigation`, as ids are unique `#navigation` should be enough.

```
#navigation {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}


#navigation ul.nav {
    display: inline-block;    
    float: none;
}
```