# Centre the nav bar

Tags: html, css

I need to centre the links and logo in my navbar. I know one cannot centre it using float.

```
nav {
    float:left;
    padding:12px 0 0 0;
```

}

```
<nav>
           <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html"><img alt="Eni Gma" src="images/logo.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="index-3.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="index-4.html">Contacts</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722693/center-menu-navigation

Comment: `nav {margin:auto;}` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/RZ3ES/

```
nav {
    padding:12px 0 0 0;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zA57y/1/)

CSS:

```
nav{
    text-align:center;
}

li{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:12px 0 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the width of your nav bar, you can use:

```
nav {
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4N6Wy/

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

1) Wrap everything left from it in a class like "float-left", everything right in "float-right"

2) Float the two wrappers.

3) Then set 
    nav { text-align: center; }